# MacBook 2017 (USB-C) to Apple Cinema Display 30"

Tags: mac, cinema-display

I've seen many of the solutions on the topic, all posted in this site. But I haven't seen any of them mentioning Apple's adapter, [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB571LL/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter)

I have that, which was used to connect to my old MacBook Pro 2013.

Now, I'm assuming that all I need is to connect the Mini DisplayPort to an adapter, such as [AllSmartLife USB C Type to Mini DisplayPort/Mini DP Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017TZTMBG) (as mentioned in one of the posts) and the USB cable to a USB-C adaptor.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

When selecting an adapter, you have to know what sources you are going from to what you are going to.  One important thing to keep in mind is that you want to limit the number of conversions/connections you make; more conversions = less reliability.

The [2017 MacBook](https://www.apple.com/macbook/specs/) has just a single USB-C port.  However, it supports the following:

> - Charging
> - USB 3.1 Gen 1 (up to 5 Gbps)
> - **Native DisplayPort 1.2 video output**
> - VGA output using USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter (sold separately)
> - HDMI video output using USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (sold separately)

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The Apple Cinema Display has a *Dual Link DVI port*.

So, you need to go from USB-C DisplayPort to DualLink DVI Adapter like the [Tripp-Lite U444-003-D](http://radnex.us/usbc-dvi-dual-link) (The product **must** indicate that it supports Dual-Link DVI or it won't work)

Keep in mind, that this particular display is getting long-in-the-tooth so to speak and it will become increasingly difficult to find newer interfaces for older, unsupported monitors that has a small market share (Everybody had DVI, only a few could afford DL-DVI).

Comment: Thank you for this. The solution I found to this problem is as follows (with cables coming from Cinema Display to Mac): (1) monitor cables connect to Apple's Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter; (2) The USB cable connects to a USB-to-USB-C adaptor; (3) the MiniDisplay Port cable connects to a MiniDisplayPort-to-USB-C adaptor (I used the one from AllSmartLife, as recommended by another poster). Monitor works at full resolution.

Comment: @rgda I would love links to these cables and adaptors. I can't get this setup to work on my end. :/

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem and after much search, came to this solution:

1. Dual-Link DIV to DisplayPort using Apple's connector
2. [DisplayPort to USB-C using this connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079CBNK8M) Which is a  USB-C to Mini-DisplayPort and Charging Port Adapter {Amazon.com}

Keep in mind that the Cinema display also needs a USB-A connection (I'm guessing to provide power to some internal circuit for link negotiation?), so you'll need a separate adapter from USB-C to USB-A.

I'm also an amateur photographer and shoots with a Canon 5DsR, editing my photos using an AdobeRGB LG 4K display (10-bit color to support AdobeRGB). I've also tested the DisplayPort adapter on this display and it works flawlessly.

On a side note - reason why you'll need a separate adapter for USB-A instead of having the USB-A built-in to the DisplayPort adapter is that only way for USB-C to support DisplayPort data-rate is using Display Protocol, which turns a bi-directional USB connection (10Gbit/direction) to a uni-directional output port (20Gbit total). If you work out the math: 3840 * 2160 * 10-bit color per channel * 3 color channels (RGB) * 60 Hz = 15Gbit/s.